# Swift: unrecognized selector sent to instance from UIView but fine when in a UICollectionView cell

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a UIButton in my app, the title label of which is set to be a phone number. When the user taps the button, I'd like to call the number shown.

This works fine when the button is rendered in a UICollectionViewCell, however when it is just in a UIView, I get the above error?

What am I missing?

Code as follows:

From the UICollectionViewCell (works)

```
cell.phoneButton.setTitle("\(tmpDict["ContactPhone"] as! String)", for: .normal)
cell.phoneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(phoneInteraction().makeCall(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

From a UIView (Fails with error)

```
self.subjectPhoneButton.setTitle("\(item["tel"] as! String)", for: .normal)
self.subjectPhoneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(phoneInteraction().makeCall(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

My class which makes the call

```
open class phoneInteraction {

@objc func makeCall(sender: UIButton) -> Bool {

    let phoneNumber = sender.currentTitle
    var editedPhoneNumber = ""

    if phoneNumber != "" {

        for i in (phoneNumber?.characters)! {

            switch (i){
            case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9" : editedPhoneNumber = editedPhoneNumber + String(i)
            default : print("Removed invalid character.")
            }
        }

        let phone = "tel://" + editedPhoneNumber
        let url = NSURL(string: phone)
        if let url = url {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        return false
    }

    return true
}

}
```

Comment: Start by removing the parens from phoneInteraction(). this is how I typically use a selector: #selector(ViewController.normalTap)). Even though I don't name the parameter of sender, the sender is available in the called method.

Comment: The console error message also tells you the name of the unrecognized selector. Can you confirm that it is phoneInteraction? If it isn't, then we need more code.

Comment: Confirmed, it is phoneInteraction that is causing the issue.

I tried removing the parentheses and there was no change. Also removed the parameter name and it complained it was not provided. 

Interestingly, if I add the makeCall function into the UIViewController itself, it works. However, this is not desirable as I'd like to hive off function such as these in a single class I can reference from anywhere.

Comment: I'm not at my computer just now. I'll take another look when I get back.  A thought though: you could put it in an extension and then be able to access it anywhere.

Comment: Can you make your class a subclass of nsobject? You wouldn't need the @objc qualifier on the method.

Comment: Sorry, I've been unavailable to test this for the last few days.
I've just returned and tried all of the above and still no change. 

The only thing I haven't done is create an extension.

Error returned is:  

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[App.subjectLocation makeCallWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa8c5803e00'

Comment: I've been able to reduce it: extension Selector {
    static let makeCoffeeNotification = #selector(Customer.drink(_:))
}

class Customer {
    @objc func drink(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Mmm... Coffee")
    }
}
With an error message of Type 'Customer' has no member 'drink'. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Ok thank you. It'll have to go in the same class that calls it then. Shame, but it is what it is.